# Unquote a value while constructing JSON Object in MySql query

Tags: mysql

MySql version 5.7.12

**Query**

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(unix_timestamp(created_time),JSON_OBJECT(status,cast(concat(count(status))as char))) FROM table_name where  status='NEW'  and unix_timestamp(created_time) between 1512543400 and 1532716199 GROUP BY unix_timestamp(created_time);
```

**Result**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_OBJECT(unix_timestamp(created_time),JSON_OBJECT(status,cast(concat(count(status))as char))) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"1526447587": {"NEW": "1"}}                                                                     |
| {"1530170666": {"NEW": "1"}}                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to unquote the value "1" like following, how to do this ??

```
{"1526447587": {"NEW": 1}}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the cast to `char`, i.e. use `JSON_OBJECT(status, count(status))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the cast to `char`:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), JSON_OBJECT('hello', 312)) AS output
FROM dual
```

This outputs:

```
{"1532691464": {"hello": 312}}
```

### Demo